# Common .NET-Class (i.e. List<T>)-Implementations in TypeScript

Tags: .net, github, typescript

If you know TypeScript, you probably know the DefinitelyTyped-Repository.
I was wondering if there's something similar, but with .ts-Files of .NET-Like-features?

So for example if I like the Queue-Class from .NET and I was wondering if anybody did an implementation in TypeScript, I could look it up there - or if I made an Implementation, I would know where to store it.

As I guess most TypeScript-Users are with a .NET-Background, I think that would make sense and I hope that someone thought the same already :)?

Cheers!

Comment: I think the closest Microsoft every came to creating a very shallow emulation of common .NET patterns was when they built the Microsoft Ajax library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536(v=vs.100).aspx. The better thing though is to consider whether it's needed, as there's lots of goodness in just a basic JavaScript Array for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a project that implments a bunch of these generic `<T>` datastructures:

```
- Linked List
- Dictionary
- Multi Dictionary
- Binary Search Tree
- Stack
- Queue
- Set
- Bag
- Binary Heap
- Priority Queue
```

Source : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections

E.g. a set :

```
/// <reference path="collections.ts" />
var x = new collections.Set<number>(); 
x.add(123);
x.add(123); // Duplicates not allowed in a set so will get filtered out
// The following will give error due to wrong type: 
// x.add("asdf"); // Can only add numbers since that is the type argument. 

var y = new collections.Set<number>();
y.add(456);
x.union(y);

console.log(x.toString()); // [123,456]
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an example implementation of a generic list in [TypeScript for C# Programmers](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/typescript-c-sharp-programmers) (Free from InfoQ).

TypeScript doesn't have its own framework class library, so unless there are plans for the TypeScript team to start work developing one the community will need to create one. The good news is that TypeScript has all the language features required and it should be trivial to make it modular so you only load the elements of the FCL that you need to use (using a module loader). For example:

```
import collections = require('fcl/collections');

var customers = new collections.List<Customer>();
```

Comment: Hi Steve. thanks, awesome work, looking forward to read it.
I know that TypeScript don't offer those things out of the box. But I was hoping that some other people already did something like this.

Comment: I'd be interested in an open source project that provided an FCL. Especially if it were to use something like C# to get ideas for structure as it would mean things would be in non-surprising places. Are you on GitHub?

Comment: Not yet, but I would love to start such a Project with someone like you! Until now, I was only active on Codeplex. I will contact you later that day through the contact-form on your website.